inserting a date time range into postrgres (TSTZRANGE)
I am a have a database field
sys_period = Column(TSTZRANGE, nullable=False, index=True)
when I insert a value into it is ignored the field is assigned a current timestamp like seen bellow:
[2024-04-24 05:18:03.179910+02:00, None)


when I have actually set it up to be sys_period="[2018-10-01 00:00:00Z, 2018-10-31 23:59:59Z)"
